# BitArray to zeros and ones

Tags: c#, bitarray

I have this segment of code ...

```
string rand = RandomString(16);
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rand);
BitArray b = new BitArray(bytes);
```

The code converts string to Bitarray properly. Now I need to convert the BitArray to zeros and ones.
I need to manipulate with zeros and ones variables (i. e. not for representation perposes [without left zeros padding] ). Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BitArray` class is the ideal class to use in your case for bitwise operations. You probably do not want to convert `BitArray` to `bool[]` or any other type if you want to do boolean operations. It stores `bool` values efficiently (1 bit for each) and provides you the necessary methods to do bitwise operations.

`BitArray.And(BitArray other)`, `BitArray.Or(BitArray other)`, `BitArray.Xor(BitArray other)` are for boolean operations and `BitArray.Set(int index, bool value)`, `BitArray.Get(int index)` to work with individual values.

**EDIT**

You can manipulate values individually using any bitwise operations:

```
bool xorValue = bool1 ^ bool2;
bitArray.Set(index, xorValue);
```

You can have a collection of `BitArray`'s of course:

```
BitArray[] arrays = new BitArray[2];
...
arrays[0].And(arrays[1]); // And'ing two BitArray's
```

Comment: +1, Use of `BitArray` class is more elegant way to perform bitwise operations instead of performing same operations on BigInteger

Comment: Mmm, your answer seems to be useful for me, but I have two question for you, 1- can I manipulate with each bit in the bitarray in different ways, e. g.  I do xor for first bit , and for second bit , complement for third bit and so as. ?? 2- can I declare array of bit array?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform **bitwise operations** on `Byte[]`,you can use `BigInteger` class.

1. Use `BigInteger` class constructor `public BigInteger(byte[] value)` to convert it into 0 and 1.
2. Perform bitwise operations on it.

   ```
   string rand = "ssrpcgg4b3c";
   string rand1 = "uqb1idvly03";
   byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rand);
   byte[] bytes1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rand1);
   BigInteger b = new BigInteger(bytes);
   BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger(bytes1);
   BigInteger result = b & b1;
   ```

BigInteger class supports BitWiseAnd and BitWiseOr

Helpful link: [BigInteger class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Operators in BigInteger class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4)

Comment: No, I don't want a booleans because I need to do bitwise and other operations on it. however the bitarray gives me (true and false variables) and unfortunately  this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Do you want to perform bitwise operations on each bit present in a byte or single bit? simplified question: do you want to iterate through each bit (each 0/1) or each byte? Correct me if I understood it in wrong way

Comment: I want to perform bitwise operations on each bit present in a single bit

Answer (score 0):

You can get 0 and 1 `integer` array from `BitArray`.

```
string rand = "yiyiuyiyuiyi";
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rand);
BitArray b = new BitArray(bytes);
                
int[] numbers = new int [b.Count];
                
for(int i = 0; i<b.Count ; i++)
{
    numbers[i] = b[i] ? 1 : 0;
    Console.WriteLine(b[i] + " - " + numbers[i]);
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://rextester.com/EKBZM39316)